# Android mobile menu behavior

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, wordpress

We seem to be running into an issue in regard to Android devices when it comes to the opening action of our menu navigation for the Ashoka theme in Wordpress.

### The issue described;

The menu on Android seems to only work after it fails one time to deliver the desired behaviour. After that it works as intended. But ofcourse for the love of god, we have no idea as to why it would have to fail to work.

It is working without any issues on both desktop (IE / FF / Chrome / Opera / Safari) / iOS devices.

It comes however in two situations;

1 -  If you click the site logo, the arrow below it seems to do a closing action (which it should not because it is not opened yet)

2 - A second issue (also only on Android) is that if we click the arrow below the logo (before we clicked the logo and it failed) then it seems to redirect us to a random page.

### What are we using

- Wordpress (4.4.1)
- Wordpress theme Ashoka

### For quick reference

I have attached both the custom.js

If anybody can test and give any feedback to help us further solve this that offcourse would be more then awesome.

If you need any additional information please feel free to let us know!
In advance, thanks for all your thoughts and replies, very much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Patrick

Custom js: http://inhoudgemert.patrickdankers.nl/wp-content/themes/ashoka/js/custom.js

Comment: please always put the required code that can reproduce the problem as codeblock or snippet into the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Ah offcourse, I understand.  I kept the JS external as it exceeded the allowed body size.  Let me see if I can get that included in some fashion.

Answer (score 0):

We have taken this up with some people locally and have came to realise there where some issues with the custom.js implementation used in this theme. We have added additional logic to correctly adjust the menu behaviour.

Sadly it has become quite a change which is somewhat harder to replicate. But go give a general idea please take a look at; https://jsfiddle.net/dsrqpz0h/11 in which we have depicted a scenario which should work correctly also on Android.

Escpecially we have added the needed unbinds / binds for click / tap / mouseenter;

```
function bindOpen() {
    //unbind close functions
  $('#menu').unbind('click');

  //bind open functions
  $('#menu').tap(openFunction);
  $('#menu').mouseenter(openFunction);
}
```

Once again thanks for all the views and replies none the less!